# Does binding use threads?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-databinding

I use Android databinding library:

```
android.dataBinding
{
  enabled = true
}
```

I do have a custom view. To this custom view I data bind a view model. At the time I call the data bind method I also want to load additional data from the SQLite database (I use the sqlite3.c and header file). This call to the database happens within the view model at the time the view model is bound.

The data loading always fails with a `segmentation fault` at `sqlite3_mutex_enter()`. If I load the data to the view model before or after the data binding happened the exact same code works.

To my understanding of [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mutex_alloc.html) the `sqlite3_mutex_enter()` only fails if there has already another thread entered the mutex.

I can't see where this would happending. **So I'm wondering if Android databinding library uses a thread or not?**

Comment: I would like to know why the question was downvoted? Is there anything I could add to the question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Binding happens on the UI thread.  I'm not sure why you are getting the exception, but it is good practice for the ViewModel to fetch data from the database in a background thread. I wrap my database calls in ContentProviders and then use `CursorLoader` in ViewModel to perform the threading for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using the c library of sqlite. I'm checking if it makes sense in this case to put the data loading in a background thread as you suggest.